# How to handle long running procedure(running up to 2-4 hour) from front end in dot net core

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have written a procedure which takin too much time up to 4 hour.
when I am calling it from front end in dot net core it shows time out or application get busy.
so I want to know that is there any way by which I can only start the procedure and not waiting for response and procedure executed in back end continuously.

below is my procedure:-

Table MATCSECURITYRAWETL contains 160 thousand data

CREATE Proc UpdateQuaterlyHistory
As
Begin
Declare @PeerGroup Varchar(500),@RARTicker  Numeric(18,15),@RARDeltaTicker Numeric(18,15),@RARBenchMark Numeric(18,15),@Result Varchar(10)
,@Qtr1Result Varchar(50),@Qtr2Result Varchar(50),@Qtr3Result VArchar(50),@UserName Varchar(100)='Admin'

```
Declare @QYear VArchar(10),@QMonth VArchar(10),@QuarterNO VArchar(5), @CUSIP  VArchar(150), @Description  VArchar(250),@Issuer_Display  VArchar(75), @Issuer  VArchar(25), 
@Ticker  VArchar(25), @Symbol  VArchar(25), @AssetType  VArchar(25), @Category_Display  VArchar(100), @Category  VArchar(25), @CategoryBoxDesc  VArchar(25), 
@MorningstarCategory  VArchar(25), @StyleCode  VArchar(25), @BroadAssetClass  VArchar(25), @AssetClass  VArchar(25), @ShareClass  VArchar(25), @_12b1  VArchar(25), 
@ExpenseRatio  VArchar(25), @ExpenseRatioGross  VArchar(25), @MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt  VArchar(25), @Min401KAssets  VArchar(25), @IsSoftClosed  VArchar(25), @ClosedOn  VArchar(25), 
@Return03Year  VArchar(25), @Return05Year  VArchar(25), @StdDev03yr  VArchar(25), @StdDev05yr  VArchar(25), @Sharpe03yr  VArchar(25), @Sharpe05yr  VArchar(25), 
@R203yr  VArchar(25), @R205yr  VArchar(25), @IsETF  VArchar(10), @TradingNotes  VArchar(2000), @MaxRedemptionFee  VArchar(100),@Rank Numeric(18,0),@TickerInsertDate date

, @Bench_CUSIP  VArchar(150), @Bench_Description  VArchar(250),@Bench_Issuer_Display  VArchar(75), @Bench_Issuer  VArchar(25), 
@Bench_Ticker  VArchar(25), @Bench_Symbol  VArchar(25), @Bench_AssetType  VArchar(25), @Bench_Category_Display  VArchar(25), @Bench_Category  VArchar(25), @Bench_CategoryBoxDesc  VArchar(25), 
@Bench_MorningstarCategory  VArchar(25), @Bench_StyleCode  VArchar(25), @Bench_BroadAssetClass  VArchar(25), @Bench_AssetClass  VArchar(25), @Bench_ShareClass  VArchar(25), @Bench__12b1  VArchar(25), 
@Bench_ExpenseRatio  VArchar(25), @Bench_ExpenseRatioGross  VArchar(25), @Bench_MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt  VArchar(25), @Bench_Min401KAssets  VArchar(25)
,@Bench_IsSoftClosed  VArchar(25), @Bench_ClosedOn  VArchar(25), 
@Bench_Return03Year  VArchar(25), @Bench_Return05Year  VArchar(25), @Bench_StdDev03yr  VArchar(25), @Bench_StdDev05yr  VArchar(25)
,@Bench_Sharpe03yr  VArchar(25), @Bench_Sharpe05yr  VArchar(25), 
@Bench_R203yr  VArchar(25), @Bench_R205yr  VArchar(25), @Bench_IsETF  VArchar(10), @Bench_TradingNotes  VArchar(2000), @Bench_MaxRedemptionFee  VArchar(100),@Bench_Rank Numeric(18,0)
,@Bench_TickerInsertDate date

Declare @HistoryTicker Varchar(50),@HistoryPeerGroup Varchar(200)

DECLARE TickerList CURSOR FOR 
Select  Ticker,Category_Display From MATCSECURITYRAWETL where ISNULL(Category_Display,'')<>'' 
and ISNULL(Ticker,'')<>''
Open TickerList
Fetch Next From TickerList
Into @HistoryTicker,@HistoryPeerGroup
While @@FETCH_STATUS=0
Begin 
    If Exists(Select ticker from V_MATCSECURITYRAWETL_Filtered  where Category_Display=@HistoryPeerGroup)
    begin
        Select top 1 @PeerGroup=Category_Display From MATCSECURITYRAWETL Where Ticker=@HistoryTicker 
        Select * Into #LowExp From V_MATCSECURITYRAWETL_Filtered order by [Category_Display] 
        Select Top 1
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [Category_Display] order by cast([ExpenseRatio] as real) asc,cast([Sharpe05yr] as real)) as [CategoryExpenseRank]
        ,Insert_Date
        ,[Category_Display]
        ,[CUSIP]
        ,[Ticker]
        ,[Description]
        ,cast([ExpenseRatio] as varchar) [ExpenseRatio]
        ,cast([Return05Year] as varchar)[Return05Year]
        ,cast([StdDev05yr] as varchar)[StdDev05yr]
        ,cast([R205yr] as varchar) [R205yr]
        ,cast([Sharpe05yr] as varchar)[Sharpe05yr]
        ,cast([MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt] as varchar)[MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt]
        ,cast([Min401KAssets] as varchar)[Min401KAssets]
        ,TradingNotes,AssetClass As AssetClass,AssetType As AssetType,Category As Category
        ,Issuer_Display As Issuer_Display,Issuer As Issuer
        ,CategoryBoxDesc As CategoryBoxDesc,BroadAssetClass As BroadAssetClass,ShareClass As ShareClass,IsSoftClosed As IsSoftClosed
        ,ClosedOn As ClosedOn,IsETF As IsETF,MaxRedemptionFee As MaxRedemptionFee,StyleCode As StyleCode,
        ExpenseRatioGross As ExpenseRatioGross,MorningstarCategory As MorningstarCategory
        ,StdDev03yr As StdDev03yr,Sharpe03yr As Sharpe03yr,R203yr As R203yr,'' As _12b1,Return03Year As Return03Year,Symbol As Symbol,'0' As Return01Year,'' As Sharpe01yr
        ,'' As R201yr,'' As StdDev01yr into #TickerData
        from MATCSECURITYRAWETL Where Ticker=@HistoryTicker

        Select top 1   * into #TickerData1 from  #LowExp  where Category_Display=@PeerGroup order by ExpenseRatio,[Category Expense Rank]  
   
         Select Top 1
         @TickerInsertDate=Insert_Date
        ,@Rank= [CategoryExpenseRank]
        ,@Category_Display=[Category_Display]
        ,@CUSIP=Cast([CUSIP] AS Varchar)
        ,@Ticker=[Ticker]
        ,@Description=[Description]
        ,@ExpenseRatio=cast([ExpenseRatio] as varchar)
        ,@Return05Year=Cast(case when isnumeric([Return05Year])=1 then Return05Year else '0' end As varchar)
        ,@StdDev05yr=Cast(case when isnumeric([StdDev05yr])=1 then [StdDev05yr] else '0' end As varchar)
        ,@R205yr=Cast(case when isnumeric([R205yr])=1 then [R205yr] else '0' end As varchar)
        ,@Sharpe05yr=Cast(case when isnumeric([Sharpe05yr])=1 then [Sharpe05yr] else '0' end As varchar)
        ,@MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt=[MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt]
        ,@Min401KAssets=[Min401KAssets]
        ,@TradingNotes=TradingNotes
        ,@AssetClass=AssetClass
        ,@AssetType=AssetType
        ,@Category= Category
        ,@Issuer_Display=Issuer_Display
        ,@Issuer=Issuer
        ,@CategoryBoxDesc=CategoryBoxDesc,@BroadAssetClass=BroadAssetClass,@ShareClass=ShareClass,@IsSoftClosed=IsSoftClosed  
        ,@ClosedOn=ClosedOn,@IsETF= IsETF,@MaxRedemptionFee= MaxRedemptionFee,@StyleCode=StyleCode,
         @ExpenseRatioGross=ExpenseRatioGross,@MorningstarCategory= MorningstarCategory
        ,@StdDev03yr=Cast(case when isnumeric(StdDev03yr)=1 then StdDev03yr else '0' end As varchar)
        ,@Sharpe03yr=Cast(case when isnumeric(Sharpe03yr)=1 then Sharpe03yr else '0' end As varchar)
        ,@R203yr=Cast(case when isnumeric(R203yr)=1 then R203yr else '0' end As varchar)
        ,@Return03Year=Cast(case when isnumeric(Return03Year)=1 then Return03Year else '0' end As varchar)
        ,@Symbol= Symbol ,@_12b1=_12b1
        from #TickerData 

         Select Top 1
         @Bench_TickerInsertDate=Insert_Date
        , @Bench_Rank= [Category Expense Rank]
        ,@Bench_Category_Display=[Category_Display]
        ,@Bench_CUSIP=[CUSIP]
        ,@Bench_Ticker=[Ticker]
        ,@Bench_Description=[Description]
        ,@Bench_ExpenseRatio=[ExpenseRatio]
        ,@Bench_Return05Year=case when isnumeric([Return05Year])=1 then [Return05Year] else '0' end 
        ,@Bench_StdDev05yr=case when isnumeric([StdDev05yr])=1 then [StdDev05yr] else '0' end 
        ,@Bench_R205yr=case when isnumeric([R205yr])=1 then [R205yr] else '0' end 
        ,@Bench_Sharpe05yr=case when isnumeric([Sharpe05yr])=1 then [Sharpe05yr] else '0' end 
        ,@Bench_MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt=[MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt]
        ,@Bench_Min401KAssets=[Min401KAssets]
        ,@Bench_TradingNotes=TradingNotes
        ,@Bench_AssetClass=AssetClass
        ,@Bench_AssetType=AssetType
        ,@Bench_Category= Category
        ,@Bench_Issuer_Display=Issuer_Display
        ,@Bench_Issuer=Issuer
        ,@Bench_CategoryBoxDesc=CategoryBoxDesc,@Bench_BroadAssetClass=BroadAssetClass,@Bench_ShareClass=ShareClass,@Bench_IsSoftClosed=IsSoftClosed  
        ,@Bench_ClosedOn=ClosedOn,@Bench_IsETF= IsETF,@Bench_MaxRedemptionFee= MaxRedemptionFee,@Bench_StyleCode=StyleCode
        ,@Bench_ExpenseRatioGross=ExpenseRatioGross,@Bench_MorningstarCategory= MorningstarCategory
        ,@Bench_StdDev03yr=case when isnumeric(StdDev03yr)=1 then StdDev03yr else '0' end 
        ,@Bench_Sharpe03yr=case when isnumeric(Sharpe03yr)=1 then Sharpe03yr else '0' end 
        ,@Bench_R203yr= case when isnumeric(R203yr)=1 then R203yr else '0' end 
        ,@Bench_Return03Year=case when isnumeric(Return03Year)=1 then Return03Year else '0' end 
        ,@Bench_Symbol= Symbol ,@Bench__12b1=_12b1 
        from #TickerData1 

        set @RARTicker=dbo.CalculateRAR(@Return05Year,@Return03Year,0,@StdDev05yr,@StdDev03yr,0)
        set @RARBenchMark=dbo.CalculateRAR(@Bench_Return05Year,@Bench_Return03Year,0,@Bench_StdDev05yr,@Bench_StdDev03yr,0)
        set @RARDeltaTicker=dbo.CalculateRARDelta(@RARBenchMark,@Return05Year,@Return03Year,0,@StdDev05yr,@StdDev03yr,0)

        set @QYear=YEAR(GETDATE())
        set @QMonth=Month(GETDATE())
        set @QuarterNO=dbo.GetQuarter(@QMonth)

        if(Cast(@RARDeltaTicker AS Numeric(18,4))<=0)
        begin
            set @Result='PASS'
        end
        else
        begin
            set @Result='CAUTION'
        end

        if Exists(Select ID From QuarterlyUserTickerDataMaster_Clone Where QYear=@QYear and QuarterNO=@QuarterNO  And Ticker=@Ticker)
        begin
            Declare @QID Numeric(18,0)
            Select @QID=ID From QuarterlyUserTickerDataMaster_Clone Where QYear=@QYear and QuarterNO=@QuarterNO And Ticker=@Ticker
    
            Update QuarterlyUserTickerDataMaster_Clone Set QYear=@QYear,QMonth=@QMonth,QuarterNO=@QuarterNO,CUSIP=@CUSIP,Description=@Description,Issuer_Display=@Issuer_Display,Issuer=@Issuer
            ,Ticker=@Ticker,Symbol=@Symbol,AssetType=@AssetType,Category_Display=@Category_Display,Category=@Category,CategoryBoxDesc=@CategoryBoxDesc,MorningstarCategory=@MorningstarCategory
            ,StyleCode=@StyleCode,BroadAssetClass=@BroadAssetClass,AssetClass=@AssetClass,ShareClass=@ShareClass,_12b1=@_12b1,ExpenseRatio=@ExpenseRatio,ExpenseRatioGross=@ExpenseRatioGross
            ,MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt=@MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt,Min401KAssets=@Min401KAssets,IsSoftClosed=@IsSoftClosed,ClosedOn=@ClosedOn,Return03Year=@Return03Year,Return05Year=@Return05Year
            ,StdDev03yr=@StdDev03yr,StdDev05yr=@StdDev05yr,Sharpe03yr=@Sharpe03yr,Sharpe05yr=@Sharpe05yr,R203yr=@R203yr,R205yr=@R205yr,IsETF=@IsETF,TradingNotes=@TradingNotes
            ,MaxRedemptionFee= @MaxRedemptionFee,UpdateBy=@UserName,UpdatedDate=GETDATE(),QtrResult=@Result,RAR=@RARTicker,RARDelta=@RARDeltaTicker,BenchTicker=@Bench_Ticker,BenchTickerRAR=@RARBenchMark
             Where ID=@QID
        end
        else    
        begin
            insert into QuarterlyUserTickerDataMaster_Clone(QYear,QMonth,QuarterNO,CUSIP,Description,Issuer_Display,Issuer,Ticker,Symbol,AssetType,Category_Display,Category
           ,CategoryBoxDesc,MorningstarCategory,StyleCode,BroadAssetClass,AssetClass,ShareClass,_12b1,ExpenseRatio,ExpenseRatioGross,MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt,Min401KAssets
            ,IsSoftClosed,ClosedOn,Return03Year,Return05Year,StdDev03yr,StdDev05yr,Sharpe03yr,Sharpe05yr,R203yr,R205yr,IsETF,TradingNotes,MaxRedemptionFee,CreateBy,CreatedDate,QtrResult
            ,BenchTicker,RARDelta,RAR,BenchTickerRAR)
            values(@QYear,@QMonth,@QuarterNO,@CUSIP,@Description,@Issuer_Display,@Issuer,@Ticker,@Symbol,@AssetType,@Category_Display,@Category
            ,@CategoryBoxDesc,@MorningstarCategory,@StyleCode,@BroadAssetClass,@AssetClass,@ShareClass,@_12b1,@ExpenseRatio,@ExpenseRatioGross,@MiniQualPlnsInitPurchAmt,@Min401KAssets
            ,@IsSoftClosed,@ClosedOn,@Return03Year,@Return05Year,@StdDev03yr,@StdDev05yr,@Sharpe03yr,@Sharpe05yr,@R203yr,@R205yr,@IsETF,@TradingNotes,@MaxRedemptionFee,@UserName,GETDATE(),@Result
            ,@Bench_Ticker,@RARDeltaTicker,@RARTicker,@RARBenchMark)
        end

        Declare @QYearList Varchar(10),@QuarterNoList Varchar(10),@Res Varchar(10)='',@res1 VArchar(10)
        ,@QtrYear1 Varchar(20),@QtrYear2 Varchar(20),@QtrYear3 Varchar(20)
        ,@res2 VArchar(10),@res3 VArchar(10),@Count int=0 
        DECLARE QTRList CURSOR FOR      
        Select QYear,QNo from dbo.GetLastThreeQuarter(@QYear,@QuarterNO)    

        OPEN QTRList    

        FETCH NEXT FROM QTRList     
        INTO @QYearList,@QuarterNoList     

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
        BEGIN   
            Set @Count=@Count+1
            set @Res=null
            Select @Res=isnull(QtrResult,'') From  QuarterlyUserTickerDataMaster_Clone Where QYear=@QYearList And QuarterNO=@QuarterNoList And Ticker=@Ticker 

            if(@Count=1)
            begin
                Set @res1=ISNULL(@Res,'NA')
                Set @QtrYear1=ISNULL(@QYearList,'NA')+' QTR- '+ISNULL(@QuarterNoList,'')
            end
            else if(@Count=2)
            begin
                Set @res2=ISNULL(@Res,'NA')
                Set @QtrYear2=ISNULL(@QYearList,'NA')+' QTR- '+ISNULL(@QuarterNoList,'')
            end
            else if(@Count=3)
            begin
                Set @res3=ISNULL(@Res,'NA')
                Set @QtrYear3=ISNULL(@QYearList,'NA')+' QTR- '+ISNULL(@QuarterNoList,'')
            end

            FETCH NEXT FROM QTRList     
        INTO @QYearList,@QuarterNoList    

    END     
    CLOSE QTRList;    
    DEALLOCATE QTRList;  
    Drop table  #TickerData
    Drop table  #TickerData1
    Drop table  #LowExp 
    end

    FETCH NEXT FROM TickerList     
    INTO @HistoryTicker ,@HistoryPeerGroup
END     
CLOSE TickerList;    
DEALLOCATE TickerList;
```

End

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.